# Is there anyway to get the label information by tracking number from UPS, USPS, FEDEX, etc?

Tags: api, fedex, ups

I want to know if is possible to get information like:
Consignee name (Destination Name) from UPS (And/or other couriers) tracking number?

My final goal is scan the tracking number and get the name of the receiver using the api from those.

Comment: That seems like it would be a huge security issue...  I hope that the answer is "no."

Comment: @Buggabill All the info is on the label so i don't see it being a major security issue unless there is a brute force situation, but each api call (with UPS and I assume with other shipping companies) requires a user name and password and they can track people who are attempting to brute force things.

Comment: @bmiskie - Of course, it is on the label.  That label was generated at the point of origin where they would need to know where it was going.   But, being able to retrieve a person's address from a tracking number is a really bad thing for an api to offer.  There is way too much potential for abuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither UPS nor any other major carrier returns the sender or recipient name in the tracking API. You're able to get location information like city, zip code and country, but not the actual name.